# Skipped 66 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So, I have an activity with Image Buttons and TextViews inside of a CardView. For some reason whenever I try to open the activity within the app it takes awhile for it to open and in the console it gives me this message: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. When I remove the image buttons the activity loads up normally? Does anyone know why?

`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Locanda La Sementa"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/semanta"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/semata"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="L’Altro Frantoio"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fran"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/frantoio"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view2"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Domus Hernica"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ernica"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/ernica"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view3"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Pizzeria la Ciocia"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ciocia"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/ciocia"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view6"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view4"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="L'Aia Antica"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/laia_antica"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/antica"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="80dp"
            android:text="More"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:id="@+id/more_Button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view6"
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Comment: Loading images can be resource intensive, and it's often recommended you do it off the UI thread. developer.android have some very focused tutorials on the topic: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Did you, perhaps, get this message on the emulator?  While everything people are saying about loading images is quite true, the emulator is slow.  If that is the only place that you see the "problem", it isn't a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ImageButton`s, the images might be too large, there might be too many images or a combination of the two. The xml attribute `android:src` uses `ImageView.setImageResource()` which does the decoding on the UI thread. Notice also the an `ImageButton` is-a `ImageView`.

See also [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using your RelativeLayout to place your children relative to each other in a non linear way consider using a LinearLayout instead. A RelativeLayout requires two layout passes to layout its content.

Also, you may want to move some views into ViewStubs if they are not displayed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I have avoided this issue by not using the xml src tag but setting the imageviewers bitmap programatically.,